# AttributeError: 'Player' object has no attribute 'player_xpos' in python

Tags: python

I have programmed the game "Pong" using `pygame` and had a good result without using object oriented programming, however now I want to rewrite the code using OOP, and then the problems started.

When trying to draw the bars (rectangles) corresponding to the players, the error mentioned in the title appears to me.

```
p1 = Player (10, p1y)
  File "PongPOO.py", line 32, in __init__
    sprite = pygame.draw.rect (window, white, (self.player_xpos, self.player_ypos, PLAYER_WIDTH, PLAYER_HEIGTH)) #pygame rect
AttributeError: 'Player' object has no attribute 'player_xpos'
```

I will copy the code so you can help me.

```
PLAYER_WIDTH = 10
PLAYER_HEIGTH = 100
PLAYER_POSY_INIT = (resY/2)-(PLAYER_HEIGTH/2)
p1y=PLAYER_POSY_INIT
p2y=PLAYER_POSY_INIT

class Player():

    def __init__(self, player_xpos, player_ypos):
        sprite = pygame.draw.rect(window, white, (self.player_xpos, self.player_ypos, PLAYER_WIDTH, PLAYER_HEIGTH)) #pygame rect
        speed = 2
```

Creating `Player` Objects:

```
    p1 = Player(10, p1y)
    p2 = Player(resx-20, p2y)
```

Comment: remove the `self` from `self.player_xpos`?.... You should probably read about classes and practice with some small examples before jumping ahead. You seem to be missing some basic understanding about the use of `self`

Comment: You need to review your tutorial on classes and instances to understand how to create and use instance attributes.  `self.player_xpos` doesn't exist because you haven't created it.  If you want it to exist, make the required assignment before you get to this line of code.  If you don't need it as an attribute, then remove `self.` from the reference -- this directly uses the function parameter to build the sprite.

Comment: Thanks to both, if it worked for me. I will be reviewing the subject a little more in depth.